# Swift Alamofire.upload: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift, alamofire, alamofire-upload

I'm getting the `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context` error in my code and I'm not sure why. I used the same method before and I never got this error before.

I saw similar posts here regarding this error, but none of the solutions fixed it for me. For example I tried changing `to` to `with` and it didn't do anything.
Any help would be appreciated.

I'm using:

1. Alamofire version 5.5.0
2. Xcode version 14.0
3. Swift version 5.0`

   ```
        Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            if firstButtonFileType == "image"
            {
                let imgData = firstButtonImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)
                multipartFormData.append(imgData!, withName: "homework", fileName: "homework.png", mimeType: "image/png")
            }

            if firstButtonFileType == "document"
            {
                multipartFormData.append(linkOfFirstFile!, withName: "homework", fileName: "homework." + firstFileExtension, mimeType: "application/pdf")
            }

            if secondButtonFileType == "image"
            {
                let imgData2 = secondButtonImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)
                multipartFormData.append(imgData2!, withName: "homework1", fileName: "homework1.png", mimeType: "image/png")
            }

            if secondButtonFileType == "document"
            {
                multipartFormData.append(linkOfSecondFile!, withName: "homework1", fileName: "homework1." + secondFileExtension, mimeType: "application/pdf")
            }

            if thirdButtonFileType == "image"
            {
                let imgData3 = thirdButtonImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)
                multipartFormData.append(imgData3!, withName: "homework2", fileName: "homework2.png", mimeType: "image/png")
            }

            if thirdButtonFileType == "document"
            {
                multipartFormData.append(linkOfThirdFile!, withName: "homework2", fileName: "homework2." + thirdFileExtension, mimeType: "application/pdf")
            }

            multipartFormData.append(defaults.string(forKey: "user_idx")!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "student_idx")
            multipartFormData.append(homework_idx.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "homework_idx")
            multipartFormData.append(defaults.string(forKey: "school_group")!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "school_group")
            multipartFormData.append(defaults.string(forKey: "database")!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "db")

        },
        with: URL_UPLOAD_FILE,
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    print(response)
                    if response.result.value != nil {
                    } else {
                        // internet connection error
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    )
   ```

Comment: Please add details like alamofire version you are using and Xcode and Swift version

Comment: Which line is causing the issue? Unrelated, but `aString.data(encoding: .utf8)!, can be simplified into `Data(aString.utf8)`.

Comment: @NiravD Just added the versions.

Comment: @Larme The error appears at the very beginning of the code, `Alamofire.upload(`

Comment: I'd start by commenting that whole code. And start writing it again letting the autocomplete helps you. Forget about all the `multipartFormData.append` for now until the method is "recognized".

Comment: Try once as @Larme mentioned